# Is there a way to change the color of the loading icon from remote data for tables built with material-table?

Tags: material-table

I'm using this library [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table) for my data table.  I get the primary color of my theme for the circular-progress loading icon.  I'd like to change it to the secondary color but I don't see any props for changing the styling for it.

```
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={[
        {
          title: "Avatar",
          field: "avatar",
          render: rowData => (
            <img
              style={{ height: 36, borderRadius: "50%" }}
              src={rowData.avatar}
            />
          )
        },
        { title: "Id", field: "id" },
        { title: "First Name", field: "first_name" },
        { title: "Last Name", field: "last_name" }
      ]}
      data={query =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?";
          url += "per_page=" + query.pageSize;
          url += "&page=" + (query.page + 1);
          fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
              resolve({
                data: result.data,
                page: result.page - 1,
                totalCount: result.total
              });
            });
        })
      }
      title="Remote Data Example"
    />
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses primary color of material-ui theme for progress component. So you can override primary color of your theme to change color. Example:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

<MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme({ palette: { primary: { main: '#abc' } } })}>
          <MaterialTable
            ...
            isLoading
          />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Currently you can not change color. We may add a class to loading or let users to override loading components.